# Cell Formatting, Conditional Formatting, or Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to get my Totals Column (column G/rows 4:16), to display "$  -" when the cells in Columns A:F are blank. Then Column G to display "$ 0.00" if I put a 0 (Zero) in any of cells in Columns A:F. 
I currently have the "Sum(A:F)" formula in column G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Formula in G4:

`=IF(AND(A4="",B4="",C4="",D4="",E4="",F4=""),"$-",IF(AND(A4=0,B4=0,C4=0,D4=0,E4=0,F4=0),"$0.00",SUM(A4:F4)))`

you can drag it to G16

**Update for format Sum**

To insert a custom format to the Sum you can use the following:
`=IF(AND(A4="",B4="",C4="",D4="",E4="",F4=""),"$-",IF(AND(A4=0,B4=0,C4=0,D4=0,E4=0,F4=0),"$0.00",TEXT(SUM(A4:F4),"$#,##0.00 ;($#,##0.00)")))`
But the result is considered as Text you have to use Value() to calculate it when needed

Comment: I had custom formatting in the cell(s) in column G, however the suggested formula over rides the custom formats. Any Suggestions on this matter?
(example:     $* #,###.00_);[Red] (-$* #,###.00);_(  $* " - "???_);_(@_)

Comment: You have to use `And` instead of `OR` in the second IF

Comment: Try formatting cells Number, Custom (you can compromise between format number ("$-" is consider as text)

Comment: I have updated the formula to use custom format

Comment: Awesome, Thank You... That definitely helped and now my spreadsheet is doing what I want it to do and looking the way I want it to. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Where the potential for trouble is with this, you're checking for two conditions.  Whether the entire of A:F is blank and if any of them contain a zero.

This will require some careful use of the words AND and OR inside your IF statement which allows for multiple tests and will simplify a little.

All IF statements use the same formula:
=IF(, , )

Start with =IF(AND(A4="", B4="", {etc until you get to F4}), "$ -", )

The above code checks to see if all of A4 to F4 are blank and enter the "$ -" you require and leaves the second part to check for zeroes.

This is OR(A4=0, B4=0, {etc until you get to F4}), 0, SUM(A4:F4))

Once the line of code is complete, you can then copy and past it for the rest of column G.